# django respite + backbone messed up when fetching url

Tags: django, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to implement REST API with [django-respite](https://github.com/jgorset/django-respite) paired with `Backbone.js`. Suppose i have :

models.py:

```
class Books(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

and views.py :

```
from respite import Views

class BooksView(Views):


    def index(self, request)
    return self._render(
        request = request,
        template = 'index/index'
        context = dict(
            books = Books.objects.all()
        ),
        status = 200,
    )

book1 = Books.objects.create(name = 'foo', author = 'bar')
book2 = Books.objects.create(name = '123', author = 'abc')
```

When i fetch it if i using `Tastypie`, it results with 1 collection and 2 models, the first model holds `book1` and the second holds `book2` with the collection holding that 2 model.

When i fetch it using using `respite`, it results with 1 collection 1 model, which the model acts like a collection(an array of model), and the collection holding that 1 model.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with respite, but I'd assume that the issue is that the JSON dict you're returning is a dictionary with one key, and all the models in that book.

You probably just want to return an array from the view, so Backbone will see it's a collection of models.

So change:

`context = dict(books = Books.objects.all()),`

to

`context = Books.objects.all(),`

Which should return an array (if respite is smart enough).